# Slicing Multindex Time (first level) TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'slice'

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice

I have the following Panda DataFrame df with a datetime Index ('Date')

```
df=
                   CP  Amount Location   
Date                                                              
2019-02-13        Bob    -5.0  Chicago  
2019-02-13        Bob    -5.0  Chicago  
2019-02-13     Marina   -25.0      LA  
2019-02-13        Bob   -25.0      LA  
2019-02-14    Addison     5.0  Chicago  
2019-02-14    Addison     5.0  Chicago
```

If I wanted to find all values for February 2019 onwards, I know I can do:

```
df.loc['02-2019':]
```

Now let's say that I make my df MultiIndex (either pivoting and agging) with index=['Date', 'Location', 'CP']

```
df=
                               Amount  
Date       Location CP                                                     
2019-02-13 Chicago  Bob         -10.0            
           LA       Marina      -25.0       
                    Bob         -25.0              
2019-02-14 Chicago  Addison     -10.0
```

When I try to do the same 
    df.loc['02-2019':]

I get the following error

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'slice'
```

I know I could just do

```
df.loc['02-13-2019':]
```

and achieve the same results--but is there a way to do time slice on the month/year similar to a single index?
Such as

```
df.loc['2019':]
```

or

```
df.loc['02-2019':]
```

Answer (score 2):

The fact that slicing works with `strings` is really a convenience. When that fails, go back to using `datetime64` to slice, which adds 1 as the day and month when not present:

```
import pandas as pd

s = '2019'
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(s):]

#                             Amount
#Date       Location CP             
#2019-02-13 Chicago  Bob       -10.0
#           LA       Bob       -25.0
#                    Marina    -25.0
#2019-02-14 Chicago  Addison   -10.0

s = '02-2019'
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(s):]

#                             Amount
#Date       Location CP             
#2019-02-13 Chicago  Bob       -10.0
#           LA       Bob       -25.0
#                    Marina    -25.0
#2019-02-14 Chicago  Addison   -10.0
```